# failed writing data to flash TI-RTOS

Tags: c, rtos

I run this `c` code in `TI mcu`, and always get failed writing error.`"Error: failed writing zone setting to flash"`

```
#define PATTERN_ZONE_1_FLASH_OFFSET 0x100008

static int32_t saveZoneSetting()
{
    int32_t     retVal = 0;
    uint32_t    zone1, zone2, zone3, zone4;
    uint32_t    pZone[4] = {zone1, zone2, zone3, zone4};

    /* Flash calibration data */
    if(flashWrite(PATTERN_ZONE_1_FLASH_OFFSET, pZone, sizeof(uint32_t)*4)<0){
        /* Flash Header failed */
        System_printf ("Error: failed writing zone setting to flash\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return(retVal);
}
```

Error occurs when write an array, but doesn't occurs when write a variable.

Comment: Well... What are the values of `zone1`, `zone2`, `zone3` and `zone4` when you initialize `pZone`?? That seems like a definite problem. (also which TI mcu? MSP? other?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The OP has a runtime problem, not a compile time problem. Or are there certain values that can lead to not writing into the flash?

Comment: @JamesRisner No, I don't think that `flashWrite()` does _any_ check on the data to write. What if i _want_ to write all zeroes? I would really be p****d if I could not. I expect to be able to write any values I want, that is the purpose of writing data.